# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Delegate must be cleared before release

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, crashlytics

Hi I am developing an IOS application. I do not understand the cause of crash was too much for a reason. How to find the cause of this crash and I can solve. thanks

**Crash Report ; http://crashes.to/s/6aac7c4f9f2**

[image]

Comment: Are you using MRR (as opposed to ARC)?  If so I would guess you are missing a `_delegate = nil;` in some `dealloc` method somewhere.